# Chrome extension returns error: Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript') at chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So,

First of all I know absolutely nothing about coding, this code was written using chatGPT and the extensions was supposed to be fairly simple: to add a context menu item that would paste the shrug emoticon.
¯_(ツ)_/¯

After copy pasting everything GPT told me to and loading the extension it returns with error:
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript') at chrome-extension://clhgbgaponlenebleloolafgfkajgkpk/background.js:11:22

chadGPT told me this error means that "tab.id is undefined when trying to execute a script using chrome.scripting.executeScript." . It also suggested there could be a security restriction causing this error, which caused a loop of different approaches to make it work but none worked.

Here's all of the versions I've tried, they've probably mostly the same but idk maybe some changes chatGPT made after few errors are different: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/71odc2uq324e7prxuh0lh/h?rlkey=umtmyusmgwu7ewh0pruagwaop&dl=0

Tried loading it on a fresh chrome install on a windows 10 sandbox as well without anything else installed as well as made from scratch like 3 times and tried loading from different locations but nothing really helped. So surely it has to be the code right? but I just can't find what it could be, neither can chadGPT.